# Using QVTKWidget and QOpenGLWidget in the same UI?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, user-interface, vtk

I'm working on a project that uses a custom subclass of `QOpenGLWidget` to display some renderings. At the end of the `paintGL()` method it calls the widget's `update()` method to trigger a repaint event if it's visible.
Now I want to add an additional `QVTKWidget` to my Ui and I do so by using something like this:

```
QVBoxLayout* layout = findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("layout_simulation");
QVTKWidget* widget = new QVTKWidget();

// Setup arrow
vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrowSource> arrowSource = vtkSmartPointer<vtkArrowSource>::New();

[more VTK stuff...]

widget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
renderer->AddActor(arrowActor);
renderer->ResetCamera();

// Add widget to ui
layout->addWidget(widget);
```

The VTK widget is added to the ui and is working as intended. The problem is that as soon as I use the `layout->addWidget()` method **all my other `QOpenGLWidget` objects turn black** and don't display anything. Also this black is not the background color of the `VTKRenderer` because the other widgets are still black even if I change the background color of the VTK widget. I checked and the `paintGL()` still gets called in a loop but it just doesn't display anything. I'm pretty sure that I didn't use any bad OpenGL code in my widget subclass so I guess it has something to do with the internal initialization of `QOpenGLWidget` and `QVTKWidget`. The same happens if I omit all the VTK calls and just add the newly created `QVTKWidget`.

The funny thing is that if I omit the `layout->addWidget()` call, VTK opens the renderer in a seperate window and all the OpenGL widgets work without a problem. But of course I want to embed the renderer in my ui.

Does anyone have experience with this or do you know any pitfalls I might have stepped into or are there any common problems that may cause this?

BTW: I use a OpenGL 3.3 core profile with custom shaders for my `QOpenGLWidget` subclass.

EDIT: I removed my request for a 3.3 core profile and now it uses a 4.4 compatibility profile. I guess it's now using the same profile as the `VTKRenderer` so this can be ruled out as a source for the error.

Comment: Bug still present in VTK 7.1 and Qt 5.7. For me it's not just black, it crashes.

Comment: Did anyone report this the VTK bug tracker?

Comment: Sorry, I did not. I guess it would also be sensible to contribute a complete reimplementation of QVTKWidget using the most recent Qt OpenGL standards...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I don't know what exactly caused the problem but I solved it. At first I found out that there is a second widget class for VTK called `QVTKWidget2` but unfortunately it isn't fully compatible to Qt 5.4 because it uses the old QGL classes (like `QGLWidget` instead of `QOpenGLWidget`). So I started to re-implement it as a subclass of `QOpenGLWidget` which was quite straight forward. Below are the source files for my class `QVTKWidget3` that works with Qt 5.4 for anyone who is interested. I did only limited testing (because I'm still learning VTK) but simple examples like displaying a sphere work.

Again: this only works with **Qt 5.4 (beta)** because older versionen don't provide the QOpenGLWidget class!

**Header file: qvtkwidget3.h**

```
#ifndef QVTKWIDGET3_H
#define QVTKWIDGET3_H

#include "vtkSmartPointer.h"
#include "vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h"
#include "vtkEventQtSlotConnect.h"

#include "QVTKInteractorAdapter.h"
#include "QVTKInteractor.h"

#include <QOpenGLWidget>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

class QVTKWidget3 : public QOpenGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QVTKWidget3(QWidget *parent = NULL, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0, QSurfaceFormat format = QSurfaceFormat::defaultFormat());
    virtual ~QVTKWidget3();

    //! Set a custom render window
    virtual void SetRenderWindow(vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow*);
    //! Returns the curren render window (creates one if none exists)
    virtual vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow* GetRenderWindow();

    //! Returns interactor of the current render window
    virtual QVTKInteractor* GetInteractor();

public slots:
    //! Slot to make this vtk render window current
    virtual void MakeCurrent();
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to know if the context is current
    virtual void IsCurrent(vtkObject* caller, unsigned long vtk_event, void* client_data, void* call_data);
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to frame the window
    virtual void Frame();
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to start the render
    virtual void Start();
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to end the render
    virtual void End();
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to know if a window is direct
    virtual void IsDirect(vtkObject* caller, unsigned long vtk_event, void* client_data, void* call_data);
    //! Slot called when vtk wants to know if a window supports OpenGL
    virtual void SupportsOpenGL(vtkObject* caller, unsigned long vtk_event, void* client_data, void* call_data);

protected:
    //! Initialize handler
    virtual void initializeGL();
    //! Paint handler
    virtual void paintGL();
    //! Resize handler
    virtual void resizeGL(int, int);
    //! Move handler
    virtual void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event);

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
    virtual void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* event);
    virtual void enterEvent(QEvent*);
    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent*);
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent*);

    virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent*);
    virtual void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*);
    virtual void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent*);
    virtual void dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent*);
    virtual void dropEvent(QDropEvent*);

    virtual bool focusNextPrevChild(bool);

    // Members
    vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow* m_renWin;
    QVTKInteractorAdapter* m_irenAdapter;
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkEventQtSlotConnect> m_connect;

private:
    //! unimplemented operator=
    QVTKWidget3 const& operator=(QVTKWidget3 const&);
    //! unimplemented copy
    QVTKWidget3(const QVTKWidget3&);
};

#endif // QVTKWIDGET3_H
```

**Source file: qvtkwidget3.cpp**

```
#include "qvtkwidget3.h"

#include "vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h"
#include "vtkInteractorStyle.h"
#include "vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h"

#include <QResizeEvent>

QVTKWidget3::QVTKWidget3(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags f, QSurfaceFormat format)
    : QOpenGLWidget(parent, f)
    , m_renWin(nullptr)
{
    // VTK requires a compatibility profile
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);
    setFormat(format);

    // Initialize interactors
    m_irenAdapter = new QVTKInteractorAdapter(this);
    m_connect = vtkSmartPointer<vtkEventQtSlotConnect>::New();
}

// Destructor
QVTKWidget3::~QVTKWidget3()
{
  // Following line is not needed.
  // get rid of the VTK window
  // this->SetRenderWindow(NULL);
}

// GetRenderWindow
vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow* QVTKWidget3::GetRenderWindow()
{
    if (this->m_renWin == nullptr)
    {
        // create a default vtk window
        vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow* win = vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow::New();
        this->SetRenderWindow(win);
    }

    return this->m_renWin;
}

// SetRenderWindow
void QVTKWidget3::SetRenderWindow(vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow* w)
{
    // do nothing if we don't have to
    if(w == this->m_renWin) {
        return;
    }

    // unregister previous window
    if(this->m_renWin != nullptr) {
        this->m_renWin->Finalize();
        this->m_renWin->SetMapped(0);

        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowMakeCurrentEvent, this, SLOT(MakeCurrent()));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowIsCurrentEvent, this, SLOT(IsCurrent(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowFrameEvent, this, SLOT(Frame()));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::StartEvent, this, SLOT(Start()));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::EndEvent, this, SLOT(End()));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowIsDirectEvent, this, SLOT(IsDirect(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
        m_connect->Disconnect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowSupportsOpenGLEvent, this, SLOT(SupportsOpenGL(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
    }

    // now set the window
    this->m_renWin = w;

    if(this->m_renWin != nullptr) {
        // if it is mapped somewhere else, unmap it
        this->m_renWin->Finalize();
        this->m_renWin->SetMapped(1);

        // tell the vtk window what the size of this window is
        this->m_renWin->SetSize(this->width(), this->height());
        this->m_renWin->SetPosition(this->x(), this->y());

        // if an interactor wasn't provided, we'll make one by default
        if(this->m_renWin->GetInteractor() == NULL)
        {
            // create a default interactor
            QVTKInteractor* iren = QVTKInteractor::New();
            iren->SetUseTDx(false);
            this->m_renWin->SetInteractor(iren);
            iren->Initialize();

            // now set the default style
            vtkInteractorStyle* s = vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::New();
            iren->SetInteractorStyle(s);

            iren->Delete();
            s->Delete();
        }

        // tell the interactor the size of this window
        this->m_renWin->GetInteractor()->SetSize(this->width(), this->height());

        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowMakeCurrentEvent, this, SLOT(MakeCurrent()));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowIsCurrentEvent, this, SLOT(IsCurrent(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowFrameEvent, this, SLOT(Frame()));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::StartEvent, this, SLOT(Start()));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::EndEvent, this, SLOT(End()));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowIsDirectEvent, this, SLOT(IsDirect(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
        m_connect->Connect(m_renWin, vtkCommand::WindowSupportsOpenGLEvent, this, SLOT(SupportsOpenGL(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void*)));
    }
}

// GetInteractor
QVTKInteractor* QVTKWidget3::GetInteractor()
{
    return QVTKInteractor::SafeDownCast(this->GetRenderWindow()->GetInteractor());
}

// Initialize
void QVTKWidget3::initializeGL()
{
    if(this->m_renWin == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    this->m_renWin->OpenGLInitContext();
}

// Paint
void QVTKWidget3::paintGL()
{
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor* iren = nullptr;
    if(this->m_renWin != nullptr) {
        iren = this->m_renWin->GetInteractor();
    }

    if(iren == nullptr || !iren->GetEnabled()) {
        return;
    }

    iren->Render();
}

// Resize
void QVTKWidget3::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    if(this->m_renWin == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    this->m_renWin->SetSize(w,h);

    // and update the interactor
    if(this->m_renWin->GetInteractor() != NULL) {
        QResizeEvent e(QSize(w,h), QSize());
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(&e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

// Move
void QVTKWidget3::moveEvent(QMoveEvent* e)
{
    QWidget::moveEvent(e);

    if(this->m_renWin == nullptr) {
        return;
    }

    this->m_renWin->SetPosition(this->x(), this->y());
}


// --------
//  Slots
// --------

void QVTKWidget3::Start()
{
    makeCurrent();
    m_renWin->PushState();
    m_renWin->OpenGLInitState();
}

void QVTKWidget3::End()
{
    m_renWin->PopState();
}

void QVTKWidget3::MakeCurrent()
{
    return;
    // Automaticly handled by QOpenGLWidget
    // this->makeCurrent();
}

void QVTKWidget3::IsCurrent(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void* call_data)
{
    bool* ptr = reinterpret_cast<bool*>(call_data);
    *ptr = (int)true;
}

void QVTKWidget3::IsDirect(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void* call_data)
{
    int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(call_data);
    *ptr = (int)true;
}

void QVTKWidget3::SupportsOpenGL(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*, void* call_data)
{
    int* ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(call_data);
    *ptr = (int)true;
}

void QVTKWidget3::Frame()
{
    if(m_renWin->GetSwapBuffers()) {
        this->update();
    }

    // This callback will call swapBuffers() for us
    // because sometimes VTK does a render without coming through this paintGL()

    // FOLLOWING NOT TESTED FOR QOPENGLWIDGET
    // if you want paintGL to always be called for each time VTK renders
    // 1. turn off EnableRender on the interactor,
    // 2. turn off SwapBuffers on the render window,
    // 3. add an observer for the RenderEvent coming from the interactor
    // 4. implement the callback on the observer to call updateGL() on this widget
    // 5. overload QVTKWidget3::paintGL() to call m_renWin->Render() instead iren->Render()
}

// ----------------------
//  Interaction handlers
// ----------------------

/*! handle mouse press event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }

}

/*! handle mouse move event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

/*! handle enter event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::enterEvent(QEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

/*! handle leave event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::leaveEvent(QEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

/*! handle mouse release event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

/*! handle key press event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

/*! handle key release event
 */
void QVTKWidget3::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::dragLeaveEvent(QDragLeaveEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

void QVTKWidget3::dropEvent(QDropEvent* e)
{
    if(this->m_renWin)
    {
        m_irenAdapter->ProcessEvent(e, this->m_renWin->GetInteractor());
    }
}

bool QVTKWidget3::focusNextPrevChild(bool)
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with vtk-6.2 and qt-5.2.1. With a few minor adaptations (to use `QGLWidget`) your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: For the record: the Bug still exists with QT5.5 and VTK7... And your solution still works. Good job!