# QOpenglWidget and QML Quick

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Which is the best or right way to implement a `QML` overlay over an existing `QOpenglWidget`? `QDeclarativeView` is deprecated and works only with `QtQuick 1.0`. This is a general question for a widget use case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using QVTKWidget and QOpenGLWidget in the same UI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944831/using-qvtkwidget-and-qopenglwidget-in-the-same-ui)

Comment: I don't use VTK and my questioin is more general and Qt introduced some new libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late for you, but I was able to make a QOpenGLWidget as an underlay. This [pointer](https://www.kdab.com/integrate-opengl-code-qt-quick-2-applications-part-2/#comment-144496) from KDAB got me started. Basically, You have to make some public wrappers around the protected QOpenGLWidget functions, initializeGL() and paintGL() for the QQuickView sceneGraphInitialized and beforeRendering signals.